# Convert a function that returns an object to a map of that object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object

**Requirements**
I have this getValidationSchema` function. My task entails converting the function that calls it to a map of an object.

Something similar to `validationSchema[EDIT_INFO] = someSchema`, and call that with all my mappings instead of a function.

```
export const validationSchemas = {
  ADD_USER: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string('Provide a username').required('Username is required'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Provide a valid email address'),
    password: Yup.string('Provide a password').required('Password is required'),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string('Provide your password again')
      .required('Password confirmation is required')
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords do not match'),
    group: Yup.string('Please select a group').required('Group is required')
  }),
  EDIT_INFO: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string('Provide a username').required('Username is required'),
    email: Yup.string().email('Provide a valid email address'),
    group: Yup.string('Please select a group').required('Group is required')
  }),
  EDIT_PASSWORD: Yup.object().shape({
    password: Yup.string('Provide a password').required('Password is required'),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string('Provide your password again')
      .required('Password confirmation is required')
      .oneOf([Yup.ref('password')], 'Passwords do not match')
  })
};
```

Here is the function I had until now:

```
const { mode } = this.props;
if (mode === ActionMode.EDIT_INFO) {
    return validationSchemas.EDIT_INFO;
}
if (mode === ActionMode.EDIT_PASSWORD) {
    return validationSchemas.EDIT_PASSWORD;
}
return validationSchemas.ADD_USER;
};
```

This is how i call the function until now.

```
validationSchema={this.getValidationSchemas}
```

And this is what I have done until now:

```
const mapValidationSchema: any;

validationSchemas[(validationSchemas.EDIT_PASSWORD, validationSchemas.EDIT_INFO,
    validationSchemas.ADD_USER)] = this.mapValidationSchema;

validationSchema = {this.mapValidationSchema}
```

I clearly am doing something wrong, as I get multiple errors and the form validation isn't working. Note that the form is in React, and TS.

**Also, I was asked to do this, but can you explain to me why is this better than a function with an if statement instead? Except looking cleaner I guess I don't see any merit to this.**

Comment: If you don't know the answer, it would be nice to actually tell me if you know, how is this thing called? Does that pattern have a name? Or where can I find some info?

Comment: What syntax is `validationSchema={this.getValidationSchemas}`?  You might consider providing a [mcve] that works in a standalone environment like [the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//) so others can more easily get to work on the issue.